# Biot coefficient as function of porosity

Tags: pressure, elasticity, porous-media

Can the Biot poroelasticity coefficient $\alpha$ be approximated as a function solely of porosity $\phi$, and if so then how (and under what conditions)?

I've read (e.g. [2.02-3 here](http://www.ga.gov.au/corporate_data/75663/Rec2014_044.pdf)) that it can, specifically $\alpha=1-(1-\phi)^{m(\phi)}$ where $m(\phi)=\frac 3 {1-\phi}$ however I haven't found any explanation or derivation. Elsewhere I've simply read that $\phi < \alpha \leq 1$ (e.g. [p33 here](http://science.uwaterloo.ca/~mauriced/earth437/Fjaer_et%20al_2008_Petroleum%20Related%20Rock%20Mechanics,%202nd%20Ed.pdf)).

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is only an empirical formula, obtained from measurements of sound velocity versus porosity in a single type of material, published in:

[Krief et al, *A Petrophysical Interpretation Using The Velocities Of P And S Waves (full-waveform Sonic)* (1990)](https://www.onepetro.org/journal-paper/SPWLA-1990-v31n6a2).